# Java custom JTable handling multiple TableModels

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Have a custom JTable class that implements dynamic tooltips that only appear when the ellipsis is shown for any value. Using that TooltipsTable class for several different TableModels.

**Question**: Is there a better approach or tighter syntax than using `instanceof` like this expanding it for the 11 different TableModels in my application?

```
public class TooltipsTable extends JTable
{
    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // will post if requested
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        int result = 0;
        TableModel tm = getModel();
        if (tm instanceof BrowserTableModel)
        {
            BrowserTableModel btm = (BrowserTableModel) getModel();
            result = btm.getRowCount();
        }
        else
        {
            DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) getModel();
            result = dtm.getRowCount();
        }
        else
        {
            ... more models
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Looking for a tighter, more-flexible / less-specific, technique if possible.

Comment: Just put `getRowCount` on a base class/interface that all your models extends/implements.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for the proverbial head thump :)

Comment: I'm assuming you know the [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface has a `getRowCount` method? I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem.

Comment: If all you want is custom [tooltips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/tooltip.html), then I recommend that you create a custom [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/table.html#renderer) rather than a custom `JTable`.

Comment: The TooltipsTable class is more involved. I'm only showing a small portion. There are several tables each with a different custom table model. The underlying issue is I'm using the FlatLaF Look 'n Feel library where some events cause it to re-sort the table but it's using DefaultTableModel when it needs to use my custom table model "getters". The combination of TooltipsTable and a table model interace should work well.  Thanks for your responses.